# Cannot migrate authority to b2clogin.com without specifying a policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Previously with the `login.microsoft.com` URI you could specify an authority without a signin policy and it would work e.g. the authority writen as `login.microsoft.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/V2.0` would work.

Now with `b2clogin.com` I have to write the authority URL as `https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_MyPolicy/v2.0/`

How do I write a b2clogin.com authority without specifying a Policy, like so
If I write `https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/`  I get the error

> IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These endpoints have been changed，and the old endpoint is not supported，please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin).

> An old endpoint may look like:
>
> ***[https://login.microsoft.com/{tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/](https://login.microsoft.com/%7Btenant-name%7D.onmicrosoft.com/)/oauth2/v2.0/authorize***

> A corresponding updated endpoint would look like:
>
> ***https://{tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/{tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy-name}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize***

The old endpoint like you are using is not supported,and now if you want to use b2clogin.com must be having policy.

Comment: That is the document I have been using but they do not provide an example of what to do if you do not have any policies specified

Comment: @k29 hi, the old endpoint like you are using is not supported,and now if you want to use b2clogin.com must be having policy.:)

Comment: Okay thanks, I've added the above to the answer as an edit, as this would be the answer to the question